# Empty pmatrix looks weird

Tags: matrices

I just noticed that an empty pmatrix looks somewhat unexpected. Namely,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{pmatrix} \end{pmatrix}\]
\end{document}
```

looks like `)(` rather than `()`. First of all, is this a bug or feature? Second, is it possible to tell LaTeX to render an empty pmatrix like `()`?

P.S.: The same thing happens if I manually add braces using `\left(\begin{matrix}\end{bmatrix}\right)` instead of pmatrix.

[image]

Comment: `\begin{pmatrix} \null \end{pmatrix}` will also render the parentheses in the expected order.

Comment: Is there any difference between `\null` and `\relax`?

Comment: `\null` is defined in the LaTeX kernel as `\hbox{}`, i.e., it is an instruction that creates an empty (horizontal) box -- in the present context, a truly empty cell inside the `array` created by the `pmatrix` environment. In contrast, `\relax` (which is a TeX "primitive" command) means, somewhat colloquially speaking, "stop whatever it is you're doing right now (and start over afresh with the next command)". In the case of `\begin{pmatrix}\relax\end{pmatrix}`, the end effect of `\relax` is to start an `array` cell, as noted in @egreg's answer.

Comment: @Mico `\relax` (or `\leavevmode` etc would be safer to insert in a modified environment as if a cell has real content a `\relax` at the end will not change anything, but adding a `\null` could change the spacing of binary oprators etc)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Thanks. I guess my comment was meant to expand my initial comment, in which I had suggested `\begin{pmatrix} \null \end{pmatrix}`. My apologies if this wasn't clear.

Comment: @Mico mostly I was musing to myself since if it's going to be changed in amsmath it would be in my lap, I suspect changes required would be too intrusive unfortunately

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's essentially expected, because the code executed for `pmatrix` is something like

```
\left(
\hspace{-\arraycolsep}
\begin{array}{*{\value{MaxMatrixCols}{c}}
<body of the matrix>
\end{array}
\hspace{-\arraycolsep}
\right)
```

so if the array is empty only the two `\hspace{-\arraycolsep}` act.

Use `\begin{pmatrix}\relax\end{pmatrix}`, the unexpandable token `\relax` will start an array cell, if you don't want to use the easier `()`.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

X$\begin{pmatrix}\end{pmatrix}$X

X$(\hspace{-2\arraycolsep})$X

X$\begin{pmatrix}\relax\end{pmatrix}$X

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It may be "expected" for TeX hackers, but certainly *not* for end users!

Answer (score 9):

One possible fix in the package would be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\renewenvironment{matrix}{%
  \matrix@check\matrix\env@matrix
}{%
  \leavevmode\endarray \hskip -\arraycolsep
}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{pmatrix} \end{pmatrix}\]
\end{document}
```

But It's not safe in general, need to think if there is a suitable guard, you need to avoid forcing an extra row in

```
   \[\begin{pmatrix} x\\ \end{pmatrix}\]
```

which should act like

```
    \[\begin{pmatrix} x \end{pmatrix}\]
```